# Nexus 5 won't connect via bluetooth to my alpine radio in my car

Tags: bluetooth-pairing

I recently bought a nexus 5 phone and tried to connect it via bluetooth to my alpine radio and it won't work.

They are visible to each other and it allows me to try to connect, but then it tells me it failed because the PIN was incorrect.

I don't see how it can be incorrect if 1 - I do not have to type the PIN anywhere and 2 - I verify multiple times before accepting the pair that the password on my phone and my radio are IDENTICAL and it still won't work.

Also, someone mentioned changing my password to 0000 or something easy and similar.. but How do I change 0000 to my default password? It doesn't give me the option to change the password for bluetooth. It generates a new password every time i try to connect

Please HELP!! I need my bluetooth :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use `0000` for both? It's the most commonly-used password for devices that doesn't ask for password, or also set as the default passwird.

Comment: How do I change 0000 to my default password? It doesn't give me the option to change the password for bluetooth. It generates a new password every time i try to connect.